# List all possible elements of a set

Tags: list-manipulation, sets

I have this two sets:

$A = \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}, \{\{\emptyset\}, \emptyset\}\}$

$B = \{\{x, \{x, y\}\} | x \in A, y \in A\}$

Now I want to list all possible elements that are in $B$. How do I do this?

Comment: Are you sure this is related to *Mathematica* and not to mathematics ?

Comment: Pretty sure, since I want the program (Wolfram Mathematica, indeed) to list the possibilities for me ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you can do this: (I will replace [EmptySet] with `ES` because I have troubles formatting it here)

```
a = { ES, {ES}, {{ES}, ES}};

b = {#, {#, #2}} & @@@ Tuples[a, {2}];
% // Column
```

> ```
> {ES, {ES, ES}}
> {ES, {ES, {ES}}}
> {ES, {ES, {{ES}, ES}}}
> {{ES}, {{ES}, ES}}
> {{ES}, {{ES}, {ES}}}
> {{ES}, {{ES}, {{ES}, ES}}}
> {{{ES}, ES}, {{{ES}, ES}, ES}}
> {{{ES}, ES}, {{{ES}, ES}, {ES}}}
> {{{ES}, ES}, {{{ES}, ES}, {{ES}, ES}}}
> }
> ```

Or even more clear way:

```
b2 = Table[{x, {x, y}}, {x, a}, {y, a}] // Flatten[#, 1] &;

b2 == b
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: Great, that's it! Many thanks!